# re-requiring sudo prompt for a password?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo, pam

By default sudo seems to cache passwords for like 5 or so minutes. ie. You do `sudo something` once and you're prompted for the password and then any subsequent sudo command you do for 5 minutes doesn't require a password be re-entered because the password is being cached.

My question is...  is it possible to uncache this password and make it so that you have to re-enter this password? Ideally, this wouldn't be a permanent change. I'm just wanting to know because sometimes I develop scripts to automate things that require I do sudo and being able to reset the cache on demand for development / testing purposes would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to run `sudo -k` to invalidate the current user's cache.

More info in `man sudo`.

Hope that helps!